# Is there a supported way (w/o modifying std_string.i) to have Java null strings translated to empty std:string?

Tags: java, swig

My java code uses null strings interchangeably with empty strings. I know that's not a good practice - we are working on fixing that, but it will take time - we don't control all of the code.

We can modify std_string.i to turn passed in null java ptrs into an empty string. But we wanted to know if there's a "built in" way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using just the javain typemap:

```
%include <std_string.i>
%typemap(javain) std::string {$javainput?$javainput:""}
```

And a corresponding typemap for the const reference case. There's almost never a need to modify the default SWIG libraries because you can selectively alter/replace/augment just the bits you want to from within your own code